# Any formula for final sentences in 長爪梵志請問經 (Dirghanakha-sutra)?

Tags: translation, buddhism

The two closing phrases of 長爪梵志請問經(Dirghanakhasutra) in Taisho's Tripitaka go as follows:

*皆大歡喜。信受奉行*

1) Although I haven't read all the texts of the Taisho'c compendium, the phrases are likely to be *standard closing sayings*. Would this assumption be right?

2) Would it be correct to translate these two phrases into English as

*[Having heard this], all the [sentient beings] rejoyced greatly[, and] started practicing the teaching [they] received* ?

Answer (score 8):

1) Yes, "皆大歡喜，信受奉行" is one of the common closing sayings in the sutras. For example,

皆大歡喜，信受奉行。《金剛般若波羅蜜經》
皆大歡喜，信受奉行。《大方廣圓覺修多羅了義經》
悉皆歡喜，信受奉行。《占察善惡業報經》
皆大歡憙，信受奉行，禮佛而退。《佛說月光菩薩經》

The other common closing saying is "皆大歡喜，作禮而去". For example,

諸比丘聞經歡喜，為佛作禮而去。《六度集經》
諸比丘聞佛所說，皆大歡喜，為佛作禮。《佛說菩薩本行經》
聞佛所說，歡喜信受，作禮而去。《佛說阿彌陀經》
一切大會，皆大歡喜，受持佛語，作禮而去。《妙法蓮華經》
皆大歡喜，作禮而去。《楞嚴經》
聞佛所說，皆大歡喜，禮佛而退。《佛說觀無量壽佛經》

---

2)
皆 all (the crowd)
大 very; greatly
歡喜 pleased; glad; joyful; happy; delighted; gleeful

皆大歡喜: "all the [sentient beings] rejoyced greatly"
Yes, the translation is correct.

信 to believe
受 to accept
奉 respectfully
行 to perform; to practice

信受奉行
believe, accept and respectfully perform/practice the teaching.

作禮 to salute
而去 then leave

作禮而去
salute and then leave